# discord.py Send Errors to Channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

In discord.py, I am trying to create an error handler that sends the error (and the command) to a Discord channel. I know that I can use `on_command_error`, but that only sends the error itself, and not the command where there is an error. How do I get the command that has an error, and send it?

My code is

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    channel = bot.get_channel(761188657045438465)
    await channel.send(event) # I am trying to send the command with error here
    await channel.send(error)
    raise error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is in the `ctx`, i.e `ctx.commmand`.

So you can send the command like this

```
await channel.send(ctx.command)
```